# SSIS: sql statement as parameter

Tags: t-sql, variables, ssis

I have a button on my site, where user clicks to export the data to excel file. The problem I am facing now is that the data gets too large (40+ mb) and the web throws time out error.

The web takes a parameter from a dropdown box, and then pass it to a stored procedure.

My solution to this is to dump the data on an excel file on a network drive instead of returning it directly to the user. The user will be notified, via msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail, once the file is ready.

I found articles on the internet showing how to pass parameter to the stored procedure within ssis, but not how to pass the whole sql statement to ssis.

I'm new to SSIS and would really appreciate a detail example.

Thank you!

**I am not familiar with the web, so I'm not interested to making any change to the web at this moment.**

Comment: If I told you that sp_send_dbmail accepts a parameter that is a query, would that help you? Completely bypass SSIS generating your export and just let it be an attachment in the email

Comment: but i need the data dump to excel. Is there a direct way to accomplish this within tsql?

Answer (score 0):

With the **ExecuteSQL Task** you can put the SQL statement in a variable, or a separate file.

In your SQL Task, set the **SQLSourceType** to either *Variable* or *File connection*.

Then for the **SQLStatement** set it to the appropriate variable or file connection.

[image]

Comment: i can't visualize of how to call the ssis with a parameter. Could you please elaborate. Maybe an example? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean passing an SQL statement into the SSIS package? If not then I misunderstood your question. I added a small image illustrating the properties I had in mind.